# Is it neccessary to decorate a classmethod at it's definition?

Tags: python, methods, decorator, class-method

There are three kinds of methods in Python's OOP concept — instance method, class method, and static method.

```
class MyClass:
    def instancemethod(self):
        return 'instance method called'

    @classmethod
    def classmethod(cls):
        return 'class method called'

    @staticmethod
    def staticmethod():
        return 'static method called'
```

It is obvious to know all three methods. Now I create a new method in a class:

```
class Test():
    def ppr():
        print('what method is ppr?')
```

It is not instance method.

```
inst = Test()
inst.ppr()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ppr() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

So it is a class method?

```
Test.ppr()
what method is ppr?
```

No `@classmethod` keyword to decorate the `ppr` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets test it out:

```
class MyClass:
    def instancemethod(self):
        return 'instance method called'

    @classmethod
    def classmethod(cls):
        return 'class method called'

    @staticmethod
    def staticmethod():
        return 'static method called'

class Test():
    def ppr():
        print('what method is ppr?')

print(type(MyClass.instancemethod)) # -> function
print(type(MyClass.classmethod))    # -> method
print(type(MyClass.staticmethod))   # -> function 

print(type(Test.ppr))               # -> function
```

As `Test.ppr` comes back as a *function* and it can be run without creating an instance - it is a `@staticmethod`.

If it was a `@classmethod` instead - it would come back as type *method*.

q.e.d.

---

My IDE shows me a warning: 'Method ppr has no argument.' which hints that you probably should either add a `self` or a `cls` and the corresponding `@classmethod` to it.

To answer your question - it seems it is not needed (at this point in time) - BUT it is prudent to declare them `@staticmethod` to make your intent clear.

Comment: This is a good answer but IMO the question doesn't really make sense in the way that python refers to methods. For example, `type(MyClass.instancemethod)` would be a `function` but `type(MyClass().instancemethod)` would be a `method`. Just like `type(Test.ppr)` is a `function` and `type(Test().ppr)` is a method.

Comment: @Axe fair comment. But I am comparing the type results of the class not of its instances - and draw a conclusion from the outputs of a correctly declared class towards the incorrectly done. My approach may only be partially correct - but I was unable to locate anything to that regard in the documentation so I went back on fiddling it out myself ;)

Comment: @PatickArtner That's fair. I was more just criticizing the question. :D

Answer (score 0):

For the normal static method , it can be called by either class or instance.

```
#called by class 
MyClass.staticmethod()
'static method called'
#called by instance
MyClass().staticmethod()
'static method called'
```

The method in `Test` class is a non-standard `static method`.

```
Test.ppr()
what method is ppr?
Test().ppr()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ppr() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```